# CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory in asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to migrate a project from asp.net Core 2.2.6 to asp.net core 3.0
In my startup I had

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("default")); 
})
```

When I update to netcoreapp3.0 I receive the following error `The type or namespace name 'CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Does anyone know what is the equivalent to asp.net core 3?

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal` is now probably internal. I don't know if there's a direct equivalent, but you can also add some code to enable cors as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/api-diff/Asp.Net/3.0.0_Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.md), you can find it is not included any more in .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with CORS Policy and .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317789/trouble-with-cors-policy-and-net-core-3-1)

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later versions, CORS  is configured differently than in earlier versions. The CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory is not used in the same way.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("yoursite")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
```

And then in your configure method

```
app.UseCors("default");
```

This must rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

I use the following lines for CORS in the startup in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                 "AllowOrigin",
                 builder => 
builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        });
```

and in Configure:

```
app.UseCors(x =>
        {
            x.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
```