# Httppost and httpput blocked by CORS in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem when i make httppost and httput (httpget is OK) to an API .net core 3.1 by an Angular 10 front, the error in console application is the famous :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:23645/api/Toolbar/Search' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5TzO.png)

this the code of my front request :

```
constructor(private Http: HttpClient) {
    this.header =  new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    )

searchToolbar(search: string): Observable<ToolbarSearchResultItem[]> {
    
    return this.Http.post(this.url + '/myController/Search', { "search": search }, { headers: this.header, withCredentials:true}).pipe(tap((response: myTyoe[]) => {
      return response;
    }));
```

this is my code in Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            log.Info("ConfigureServices");
            try
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = builder.Build();

                services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
                {
                    c.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                

            }));
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AllUsers", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
                });
                
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Error in ConfigureServices" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    try
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

in a launchSettings.json i set this :

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:23645",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
```

and in applicationhost.config:

```
 <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <add value="Negotiate" />
            <add value="NTLM" />
          </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
```

this is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("Search")]
       [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
        public IList<ToolbarSearchResultItem> Search(ToolbarSearch search)
        {
//my code
}
```

this is the detailled message in the console :Request URL: http://localhost:23645/api/Toolbar/Search
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:23645
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 6284
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Mar 2021 15:52:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:23645
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site

this is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MYEXE.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I think that it is not really a CORS block problem but a configuration problem or other, it is very similar to this question : [Trouble with CORS Policy and .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317789/trouble-with-cors-policy-and-net-core-3-1)
but I used a profiler and I don't have an SQL Problem

Comment: You have to know that is anything happened before the CORS middleware (for example if your application crash during the authorization middleware) the produced response will not have CORS header so it will appear as a CORS issue from the browser point of view. You should looked the log generated by ASP.NET (probably in the output window). If you remove your "EnableCors" attribute, is the action correctly reached ?

Comment: in the output window i don't have errors, I tried to remove the "EnableCors" attribute and I have the same error.

Comment: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "data source=MyServer;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
    ,

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },"AllowedHosts": "*"

Comment: From angular you are sending request on http://localhost:23645 but in cors you are using http://localhost:4200 . you need to use same urls

Comment: localhost:4200 is angular url and localhost:23645  is backend url and Httpget requests are OK

Comment: It works when i set allwoAnomymous to true in launchsettings but i need to log the user login that's why i should set it to false. I tried to decorate the action with AllowAnonymous but it doesn't work

Comment: Is the CORS middleware before the authorization middleware? Preflight request are never authenticated so it can cause some issue if the authorization middleware is before.

Comment: I set services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) before CORS middleware and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:23645/api/Toolbar/Search' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please note that a CORS ***[preflight request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#preflight-requests)*** (using the HTTP `OPTIONS` method) is used to check whether the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers. And the HTTP `OPTIONS` requests ***are always anonymous***, you enabled Windows Authentication and disabled anonymous access, which would cause server not correctly respond to the preflight request.

To run your app(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, to fix this issue, you can try to enable anonymous authentification to allow anonymous access.

Besides, if you would host your app(s) on IIS server, to fix this issue, you can install [IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-in-iis) and configure CORS for the app.

Comment: I agree with Frei Hand And Sergey, I activated Anonymous requests and it works ! To get user infos (that's why i activated only windows authentication before), i decorated actions by Authorize Attribute and I added this in ConfigureServices :

 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

and I removed this :

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AllUsers", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
                });

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your startup Cors config

```
     .AllowCredentials();
```

and remove from  the controller actions

```
 [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
```

But you still have have  Status Code: 401. It has nothing to do with Cors. It is only about authorization. Just comment all authorization code to test CORS. After this you can start with authorization.