# ASP.NET Core Web API CORS error multiple values and is not equal to

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I'm having this errors.
I have a windows server.
I directed server's ıp address to https://api.example.com
When I try api it works like https://api.example.com/api/test it return datas

I having an error is not equal to when my code like this:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
    policy => policy
    .WithOrigins("https://www.example.com.tr")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()

));
app.UseCors();
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/test' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

if I change the origin like https://example.com.tr I'm having multiple values error.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
    policy => policy
    .WithOrigins("https://example.com.tr")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()

));
app.UseCors();
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/test' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I added this lines to my web api's web confing file

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core  does not use `web.config` - though IIS does.

Comment: Are you using the **exact same** URI scheme everywhere? Also, you need to be using `https://` everywhere and **not** just `http://` - technically CORS doesn't require secure-contexts, but simply using `https://` everywhere _does_ solve a lot of headaches.

Comment: Also, you need both `www.` and non-`www.` versions of `Host` names _unless_ you're absolutely certain your client website (from which browsers send CORS preflight requestrs) always uses a single consistent `Host` name.

Comment: Dear @Dai thank you for answering. Yes, I'm using exact same url everywhere copy -paste also I added as you say  both www. and non-www. versions and getting "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin." error now. I know there are a lot of questions in here but ı checked all of them but it didnt solved

Comment: Rather than using `example.com` - what are the **actual** URIs/hostnames you're using?

Comment: Also, your `AddCors` code only shows you adding a _single_ Origin (`https://www.example.com.tr`) - how/where are you adding the other versions of the origins (e.g. with-and-without `www.`)?

Comment: https://myDomain.com.tr is my web site and https://api.myDomain.com.tr is my api address. both are working same localmachine on iis.

Comment: The error message says you're missing the `https://` and `www` parts though...

Comment: Dear @Dai yes you are right but as you can see I post my code in my question i add 'https://' and when add 'www' just error changing.

Comment: What error message do you get when you do that?

Comment: I think you didn't see my comment before 2 3 comment i answer that

Comment: Are you referring to _"The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin."_? If so, then that error is because an Origin needs the URI scheme: `"example.com"` by itself **is not** a valid Origin, but `"https://example.com"` is - similarly `"www.example.com"` is not a valid Origin, but `"https://www.example.com"` is - and that origin is distinct from `"https://example.com"` (and is also distinct from `"http://example.com"`) - that's why you often need multiple variations on your Origins instead of relying on a single Origin value.

Comment: I don't need multiple variations as you say. But I'm having this error i dont use 2 or 3 header with post or get methods

Comment: I can't help you any further because you aren't sharing your current actual error messages **verbatim** - even a screenshot of your browsers' dev console would help. Because you're inconsistently editing the error messages before posting them I can't tell what's accurate and what isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution on IIS server. My two website on IIS and same origin. I deleted api's HTTP response header and work for me

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the URL of your client hosted on IIS is the same as the URL configured for CORS on the server:

client site:

[image]

server-side:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
      policy => policy
      .WithOrigins("https://localhost:112")
      //...
));
```

In addition, this error may also appear when you enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS:

[image]

If this problem occurs in IIS, you may need to install [IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) and configured for the app.

For more details, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-in-iis) and [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66452279/18789859).