# Cors fail when add app.useauthentication on webapi .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I add `UseAuthentication()`; to my  `startup.cs` The Allow cors fail and the cors is not allowed, there's any order to setup please? (without app.UseAuthentication() no cors problem)

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(
options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
  ); app.UseHttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware();
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

on ConfigureServices i have :

```
  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{....       


        services.AddCors();
                services.AddSSOAuthentication(Configuration, CurrentEnvironment);
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddRequestLogging(opt =>
                {
                    opt.ResponseTimeInMs = true;
                    opt.CookiesLoggingEnabled = false;
                });
                services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an exception message?

Comment: No execption but i have blocking cors msg: (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with CORS Policy and .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317789/trouble-with-cors-policy-and-net-core-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                ...
            });
```

to ConfigureServices?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "AnyPolicyName";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                builder =>
                                {
                                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                                });
        });
    
        /** etc. **/
    }
```

**EDIT:** Also add

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    /*...*/

    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

    /*...*/
}
```