# Cors Error for HTTP but not for HTTPs in ASP.NET Webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

My Ionic-Angular front end is trying to get data from a C# ASP.NET Webapi, both hosted as Azure App services.

It works fine when using https but not when using http. [image]

I've tried different configurations in my startup.cs, but somehow it doesn't go through:

```
opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                    {
                        policy
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
            
                        // policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:8100");
                    });
```

```
   opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                    {
                        policy
                        .WithOrigins("https://cappuccinobudget.azurewebsites.net", 
                                     "http://cappuccinobudget.azurewebsites.net" )
                                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                                     .AllowAnyMethod();
            
                        
                    });
```

Any tips?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317789/trouble-with-cors-policy-and-net-core-3-1/59319161#59319161

Comment: This post needs more details.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your Cors syntax with this

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                       builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8100")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
.....

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: Could you please post your whole startup file  that has included my tips?